# Why does grep not use my variable in this shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# found if this IP is receiving data
#
#echo hexIpAdd=`sh convertIPAddressToHex $1`

hexIpAdd='C0 A8 01 02'

#`snmpwalk -v 2c -c public 192.168.252.187 .1.3.6.1.4.1.231.7.1.2.2.1.4.7.13.1.1.3301 | grep '$hexIpAdd' | wc -l`

if [ `snmpwalk -v 2c -c public 192.168.252.187 .1.3.6.1.4.1.231.7.1.2.2.1.4.7.13.1.1.3301 | grep '$hexIpAdd' | wc -l` -gt 0 ]; then
       echo "Value FOUND!!"
else
       echo "Value NOT FOUND!!"
fi
```

The code is very simple, I convert my an regular IP to a hexadecimal one, and query via SNMPWALK a network equipment to see if the converted IP is receiving streaming.

The problem is, that the grep pipe is failing to use the VARIABLE, with means if I replace the `"grep '$hexIpAdd'"` with this `"grep 'C0 A8 01 02'"` it works.

Comment: The duplicate is your main issue, although I would also suggest changing your line to `if snmpwalk -v 2c -c public 192.168.252.187 .1.3.6.1.4.1.231.7.1.2.2.1.4.7.13.1.1.3301 | grep -q "$hexIpAdd"; then`

Comment: **Thank You... it's working now**

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use single quote for quoting variable in shell
2. Use `grep -q` to avoid command substitution, piping with `wc` and `[...]` expression:

Have it this way:

```
hexIpAdd='C0 A8 01 02'

if snmpwalk -v 2c -c public 192.168.252.187 .1.3.6.1.4.1.231.7.1.2.2.1.4.7.13.1.1.3301 | 
    grep -q "$hexIpAdd"; then
       echo "Value FOUND!!"
else
       echo "Value NOT FOUND!!"
fi
```

Comment: **Thank You... it's working now**